# Huge arrows in 3D graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

H$\vphantom{a}$i. Consider the following code:

```
f1 = Plot3D[-Exp[-x^2-y^2],{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5},PlotRange->All]
f2 = Graphics3D[Table[{Arrowheads[.01],Arrow[{{2Cos[i],2Sin[i],0},{2.5Cos[i], 2.5Sin[i],0}}]},{i,0,2Pi,2Pi/40}]]
```

[image][image]

So far so good. Let us now combine these figures into a single figure:

```
Show[f1, f2]
```

[image]

For some reason, some arrows look funny: their heads are much larger than they should be. The behaviour is even weirder if we rotate the figure

[image]

What's going on here? how can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem  can be identified if you just do

```
Show[f2, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}]
```

[image: arrowheads]

I talked about this issue [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88534/245), and my suggestion would be to use the same solution here. I'd suggest just using the function `arrowLine` I defined in that answer.

Comment: Yep, this works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I looked at my suggestion of `BoxRatios->Automatic`  in the linked answer and find that it doesn't work properly here. So I'd say just use the `arrowLine` function. That `Arrowheads` stuff is just badly designed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it doesn't work properly here. I changed `Exp[-x^2-y^2]` to `3Exp[-x^2-y^2]`, and the result looks fine to me.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform if you look closely the heads are still off, at least in my plots... so I'd really say ditch the built-in arrows.