# Using Graphics3D to plot sphere upon XYZ coordinate frame

Tags: graphics3d

I think there should be an easy way to accomplish my task but I have not found it yet.  I would like Graphics3D to plot a simple sphere, radius $1$, centered on ${0,0,0}$.  And, the plot should be without a box (easy to do) but with coordinate axis that are centered on the sphere itself.  With Graphics3D those coordinate axis are outside of the sphere as if they were labeling 3 edges of the bounding box.

The surface of the sphere should be viewed as somewhat transparent where the axis inside the sphere can be viewed.

I would like guidance on how to go about this, thinking it must be a common need there must be a simple parameter that I have not yet found.  I am sure that I could construct such a 3D image manually by drawing each axis but I am hoping to avoid that.

I admit to being an novice with Mathematica graphics and especially Graphics3D.

Comment: us e `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}`?

Comment: And `Boxed -> False`? And `Opacity[0.5]` for the sphere?

Comment: You missed `Axes -> True` !

Comment: @K7PEH next time, instead of saying *"easy to do"*, please show us the code you have, so we can know how far you have done yourself. The question itself, if you share what you have learned, could be good help for other users visiting the site.

Comment: @kglr and others, thanks.  AxesOrigin was the parameter I missed.  Not sure why I did not find that as I did read everything in the documentation but last night it is possible I was also falling asleep.

Comment: @K7PEH I was going to post an alternative answer because I thought your issue about the axes floating outside of the sphere hadn't really been addressed yet. But I see you already accepted the answer - does that really mean you're satisfied? I could post my approach if you want. It's kind of a nuisance that *Mathematica* doesn't have better 3D axis options. `73`, `DB8HI`...

Comment: @Jens -- Thanks for your help and another alternative approach is always welcome.  If I had caught the AxesOrigin parameter when I read the docs in Help I would have never asked the question in the first place as it was the "simple thing" I thought should exist yet I didn't know of it.  I think I missed it entirely on reading thru the help pages and examples.  I didn't do too much though, I was busy on Field Day earlier today before it ended with battery powered Elecraft KX2 and Buddipole antenna.

Comment: @K7PEH Thanks for accepting my answer, but I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all timezones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers. I have edited my answer so you can accept the best one by Jens.

Comment: @rhermans -- Actually, your answer was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for and in fact assumed to exist in Mathematica but I just didn't see it in my reading of the docs (as I explained above).  If you re-read my question, you see that I mention "easy" and that "...there must be a parameter [to do this]".  And, you showed me that very parameter, the very one I assume should exist, the very one I in fact did use already from your info. It fit my need.  This is why I accepted your answer.  Jens answer is interesting and probably useful but his extra work was what I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)

```
Graphics3D[
 {Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}
 , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
 , Boxed -> False
 , Axes -> True
 , PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### How to go about this.

A good starting point is to look at the [documentation about `Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html), search this site, and look at the [Options](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html) of the relevant functions.

```
Options[Graphics3D]
(* {AlignmentPoint -> Center, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 AutomaticImageSize -> False, Axes -> False, AxesEdge -> Automatic, 
 AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> {}, 
 Background -> None, BaselinePosition -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {}, 
 Boxed -> True, BoxRatios -> Automatic, BoxStyle -> {}, 
 ClipPlanes -> None, ClipPlanesStyle -> Automatic, 
 ColorOutput -> Automatic, ContentSelectable -> Automatic, 
 ControllerLinking -> Automatic, ControllerMethod -> Automatic, 
 ControllerPath -> Automatic, CoordinatesToolOptions -> Automatic, 
 DisplayFunction :> $DisplayFunction, Epilog -> {}, FaceGrids -> None,
  FaceGridsStyle -> {}, FormatType :> TraditionalForm, 
 ImageMargins -> 0., ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> Automatic, 
 ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {}, Lighting -> Automatic, 
 Method -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, PlotRegion -> Automatic, 
 PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, Prolog -> {}, 
 RotationAction -> "Fit", SphericalRegion -> False, 
 Ticks -> Automatic, TicksStyle -> {}, TouchscreenAutoZoom -> False, 
 ViewAngle -> Automatic, ViewCenter -> Automatic, 
 ViewMatrix -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2.}, 
 ViewProjection -> Automatic, ViewRange -> All, 
 ViewVector -> Automatic, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Even though an answer was already accepted, let me post how I like to make axes in 3D:

First, define a general 3D arrow, called `arrowLine` (it allows a more robust way of specifying the proportions of the shape, compared to the built-in `Arrow` command). See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88534/245). Then I combine three such arrows in the function `arrowAxes` to make a coordinate system:

```
Options[arrowLine] = {Thickness -> .1, "HeadScale" -> 3};
arrowLine[{p1_, p2_}, 
  OptionsPattern[]] :=
(*p1 and p2 are 3D points. They are passed as a list*)
 Module[{p3, scale2, norm, pyramidHeight = 3/2}, 
  scale2 = OptionValue["HeadScale"]*OptionValue[Thickness];
  norm = Norm[p2 - p1];
  If[norm > scale2*pyramidHeight, 
   p3 = p1 + (p2 - p1)/norm (norm - scale2 pyramidHeight);
   {EdgeForm[], Cylinder[{p1, p3}, OptionValue[Thickness]], 
    GeometricTransformation[
     GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0, pyramidHeight}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 
        0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 
      Polygon[{{3, 4, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {2, 5, 1}, {5, 3, 1}, {5, 2, 4, 
         3}}]], Composition[TranslationTransform[p3], 
      Quiet[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, 
         p2 - p1}], {RotationMatrix::degen, RotationTransform::spln}],
       ScalingTransform[scale2 {1, 1, 1}]]]}, {}]]   

arrowAxes[forwardLength_, backwardLength_: 0] := 
 Map[{Apply[RGBColor, #], 
    arrowLine[{-backwardLength #, forwardLength #}, 
     Thickness -> .05]} &, IdentityMatrix[3]]
```

Now the 3D axes can be combined with a partially translucent sphere as follows:

```
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.7], Orange, Sphere[]}, arrowAxes[3, 3]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", Background -> Gray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The translucent effect is created by [`Opacity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html) and the axes are drawn by `arrowAxes[3, 3]`. Here, the first argument is the length of the arrows in the forward direction from the origin, and the second argument is the length in the reverse direction. You can omit the second argument to get axes that only extend in the forward direction (bordering the first octant).

Comment: Thanks for the effort in your answer.  I have copied your arrowAxes code to save for some other use I might have in the future.  However, I do have to say that the AxesOrigin option parameter is exactly what I was looking for and hoping to find for my current need.  But, I am already thinking of ways to use your code and more importantly to learn more skills in writing such things in Mathematica.